# Windows 7. Git public key configuration

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, github, ssh-keys

I have followed the instructions here: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/ to set up git on my windows 7 machine.

I can use "git bash" and run commands. I am prompted for my key's pass phrase and can successfully connect. E.g.:

```
$git push -u origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mbj/.ssh/id_rsa':
Everything up-to-date
```

Also this:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mbj/.ssh/id_rsa':
Hi markbrenigjones! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provi
de shell access.

$ which ssh
/bin/ssh
```

However, when I open a regular windows command prompt and run the same command, I get this:

```
C:\util\meta_vimrc>git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Also this:

```
C:\util\meta_vimrc>ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).

C:\util\meta_vimrc>which ssh
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe
```

How do I get this working from the non "git bash" prompt?

Comment: Make sure that your public/private key pair is in the .ssh directory, `C:\Users\Hunter\.ssh` in my case.

Comment: Thanks Hunter, I do have an id_rsa and id_rsa.pub file in C:\Users\mbj\.ssh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the program has no idea where your `HOME` directory is when running from the Windows `cmd.exe` interpreter. For this to work, the ssh configuration directory with your key has to be found, namely `/c/Users/mbj/.ssh`.

Set this by running:

```
set HOME=C:\Users\mbj\
```

Comment: Is that an environment variable? I have this:  \n

C:\Users\mbj\.ssh>set HOME  \n
HOMEDRIVE=C:  \n
HOMEPATH=\Users\mbj  \n

Comment: Needed to run: set HOME=C:\Users\mbj\

Answer (score -1):

What works for me is to run PuTTY's Pageant.exe and add your private key to it. Then plink.exe knows where to find the key no matter what.

Comment: Would I need to run that all the time? have it run at start-up?

Comment: Just tried this - pageant came back with "Couldn't load this key (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key). Sorry I'm not more familiar with SSH keys

Comment: Yeah--the idea would be to run this all the time. You may need to use puttygen.exe to export/import the key to putty's .ppk key format first.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work. I am running pageant.exe and it is loaded with the public key I added to github.com

Comment: Don't use Pageant, the road to Git Ruin™ is lined with PuTTY